# Wordpress - enqueue different stylesheet, different time of day (but with javascript not php)

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress

Edit: I updated the javascript call of adding the css class .night to the code below. Therefore, if you want to do something similar, just add in the .night before your classes into your css and it should work.

TL;DR – I'm trying to use a simple line of "if time is between X and Y, load style-day.css, else, load style-night.css" javascript within my functions.php (and not use php time) and I can't figure out how to do it.

Hi there,

I currently have a Wordpress website where I have a custom javascript file that will show dynamic content depending on the time of day.

```
if (7 <= currentTime && currentTime < 20 ) {
    console.log("It's daytime");

    initialize_Day();

  } else {
    console.log("It's nighttime");

    initialize_night();

  }
```

That works well, but I also want to show a different stylesheet depending on the same time of day. The problem is, in functions.php I use wp_enqueue_style to pull in the different stylesheets. I don't want to use a php timebase since that is server side, when I want to use javascript to match them up (and so the content loads based on the user's clock).

I tried creating a custom script, placing my code (very bottom) to call style-day.css and style-night.css and using

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'website-name-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/style.js', array(), website-name-style_VERSION, true );
```

but the stylesheet doesn't load properly – it loads, but there's a split second the site loads without a stylesheet. I realize this is the incorrect way to load stylesheets in Wordpress anyways.

Anyone have any suggestions on how I can basically add this code below into my functions.php but also keep using wp_enqueue_style?

**THIS CODE BELOW WORKS AND IS MY SOLUTION WITH THE INPUT FROM THE COMMENTS BELOW THIS QUESTION**

Instead of placing this code in my functions.php, I placed it into a javascript file, and called the javascript file in functions.php using the wp_enqueue_script line above

```
(function() {
    const currentTime = new Date().getHours();

function day() {
    document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' href='./wp-content/themes/name/style-day.css' type='text/css'>");
};
function night() {
    document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' href='./wp-content/themes/name/style-night.css' type='text/css'>");
};


if (7 <= currentTime && currentTime < 20 ) {
    console.log("time to eat");

    day();

  } else {
    console.log("time for a drink");
    document.body.classList.add("night");
    night();

  }
}());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stackoverflow.com!

1. In your night css file, prefix every selectors (IDs, Classes, tag) with `.night`  class. For example if you have a style like this `.entry {background:#000}`, change that to something like this:
   `.night .entry {background:#000}`. Mind the "space" between two class names.
2. Merge your two CSS files in one file so you omit one extra request and enqueue this file using the normal WP style enqueue routine.
3. In your JavaScript file, check for the time and if it's night just add `.night` class to your most top element (the `body` or the first element after `body`).

Description for what is happening:
The magical space between two classes name tells the browser to only apply these styles to the elements which their top most parent has `.night` class.

Remember: To ensure that your styles will applied correctly, add all of the `night` styles after the `day` styles in your single CSS file. The order matters in CSS.

Comment: That sounds like a fantastic idea. Thank you very much! I'll try it and post if this works for me/and my process to share if anyone else is looking for similar results.

Comment: Your welcome pal. Just remember to accept the answer.

Comment: There's one issue I'm having trouble with. In my css I have many css selectors called something like `body #page #inner {}` and I need to target it with `.night` but it doesn't work if I add it so it's `.night body #page #inner {}`. The `body` is important in my css since I have JS that uses css code since the JS uses this.

Comment: Hi. You should add `night` class to body element and then in your css file use the following format to target elements: `body.night #page #inner {...}`.

Comment: Thank you very much – this worked. There was a human error where I missed adding `night` to one line which caused an error.